# Upload HTTP Error in admin on file upload (Nginx)

Tags: admin, admin-panel, nginx, image-upload

I am getting the following error on uploading files in Magento admin.

```
Upload HTTP Error
```

I have added the following to my php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 200M
post_max_size = 200M
memory_limit = 512M
```

I have also added this to my nginx config

```
client_max_body_size 200m;
```

[image]

I have also toggled between https and http

Comment: Update adobe flash player. Check nginx error log. Global array $_FILES have field 'error' - check this field. Change browser. Try from mobile.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP 7  then go to

```
lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
```

Find the following code

```
$params['object']->$params['method']($this->_file['tmp_name']);
```

And replace it with

```
$params['object']->{$params['method']}($this->_file['tmp_name']);
```

Comment: fixed it for me. running magento 1.9.2.1 with php 7.0.13

Comment: worked mag v 1.9.2.4 PHP7.1.10

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the following:

php-fpm was running with the group www. the folder /var/lib/nginx was set to nginx:nginx

```
chown -R www-data:www /var/lib/nginx
```

Therefore I reset the owner on the folder to www-data:www and it works!

Answer (score 0):

HTTP upload error: Such error is received due to 'n' number of reasons like folder permission, server PHP handler, etc and solutions for the same are easily available on the web.

But in my case, everything was fine but still, the issue was not resolved. Finally, the issue was found to be with .htaccess protection applied to the Magento website. The .htaccess protection should be disabled while image uploading. Not sure why Magento behaves like this but server admins will have to care of that.