# Product page image upload issue

Tags: product-images, image-upload

Whenever i try to upload an image for product page it shows `Upload HTTP Error`.

I have cleared cache and also performed indexing and even proper permissions are given to the folder.

Comment: Please check  your  upload temp folder permission  and basically need  check  `MagentoDir/media/tmp`

Comment: dont have temp folder in media

Comment: try this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63071/upload-http-error-in-admin-on-file-upload-nginx/146216#146216

Answer (score 0):

Set you media folder (MagentoDir/media) permission to 0777.