# PHP 7.0.12 to PHP 7.0.1 Image upload broken "Upload HTTP Error"

Tags: magento-1.9, php, media, php-7, varien-file-uploader

OK so for the last year I have been using PHP 7.0.1 with my Magento website and it has been great. now all of a sudden, Plesk has updated it to 7.0.12 and now the image upload is not working.

Is there a way to specify that I want it to use PHP 7.0.1 or am i too late?

Failing that, I am guessing some code in my magento uploader is outdated. What Can I change to get My Magento website(uploader) to work with PHP 7.0.12.

I am sure this will be asked a lot in the next few months but I think this issue is a new issue.

[image]

Comment: share screenshot please

Comment: (I would comment, but I can't). This could potentially be missing extensions due to a new PHP configuration. The required extensions are can be found [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_req-prereq_ubuntu.html#php-extensions). Also, do you have any error logs?

Comment: try this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63071/upload-http-error-in-admin-on-file-upload-nginx/146216#146216